# How to call overloaded function of inherited class inside not overloaded function of a parent class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two similar classes `Son` and `Daughter` which have the same member function `ChildWrites` but different realization (polymorphism). But this function calls from another function `Write` inside `Parent` class.

```
class Parent:

  def __init__(self):
    self.__pathToPocket = "Pocket.txt"                                                          
    print 'What do you want from me, Kid!?'

  def Write(self):
    try:
      f = open(self.__pathToPocket, 'w')
      ChildWrites(self, self.__pathToPocket) 

    except IOError:
      print "Child is too weak to open file. Shame!" 

    finally:
      f.close()

  def ChildWrites(self, pathToPocket):
    raise NotImplementedError("Which of you ask for something again?")


class Son(Parent):

  def __init__(self):
    Parent.__init__(self)
    print('I am your son and ')

  def ChildWrites(self, target):
    target.write('I want money!')


class Daughter(Parent):

  def __init__(self):
    Parent.__init__(self)
    print('I am your daughter and ')

  def ChildWrites(self, target):
    target.write('I want more money!')


Michael = Son()
Michael.Write()
Anna = Daughter()
Anna.Write()
```

When I run this code I get the error:

```
What do you want from me, Kid!?
I am your son and 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test2.py", line 46, in <module>
Michael.Write()
File "./test2.py", line 13, in Write
ChildWrites(self, self.__pathToPocket) 
NameError: global name 'ChildWrites' is not defined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Very often when an inheritance-based scheme starts to feel awkward it's time to [think about a composition-based approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChildWrites` is still a method and must be called as such by prefixing it with `self.`, not by passing `self` as an argument:

```
self.ChildWrites(self.__pathToPocket)
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Stupid mistake.